# Tomcat + Eclipse with cloned project: build problems

Tags: java, eclipse, git, tomcat, servlets

I have created a project on Eclipse on my machine (let's call it "PC1"). It is a web app with some servlets and I use Tomcat to run. Instead of the `.metadata` folder, I use the Tomcat installation folder to deploy. Every servlet is configured in web.xml to be reached at the URL `[host]/myproject/myservlet/`. It runs fine on PC1.

Now I have pushed the project to a bare git repo and then cloned the repo in another machine ("PC2"). After cloning I import the project to the workspace, create the server (also here I set it up to use Tomcat's folder instead of `.metadata`) and the server itself runs fine (I see Tomcats' home page), however when I try to run a servlet using Eclipse's Run button, the following happens:

1. the browser points to `[host]/myproject/WEB-INF/classes/myservlet/` instead of `[host]/myproject/myservlet/`, so it ignores the web.xml configuration.
2. the browser displays a 404 error
3. in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder there is nothing, which I guess means that there is some build problem.
4. any other file other than servlets (e.g. jsp and html files in the 'Web Content' folder) is found by Tomcat and the content is displayed in the browser.

Any idea?

FYI I tried to clean the Tomcat work directory which was mentioned in other posts on SO, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite a common issue, that I also face sometimes when programming with large teams on the same project , sometimes someone pushes their configuration on the SVN ( we use svn but its more or less the same thing like git) that some developer accidently checks-out on his machine and eclipse's configuration goes hay-wire for him !

This is just a matter of configuration on the eclipse. Yes you pulled the exact same project to PC2 that was created initially on PC1. But the eclipse environment would be a bit different.

By environment I don't mean versions compatibility of the eclipse, I mean configurations, build-paths, project facets and whole lot of other stuff that eclipse manages on the back-end when you create a project. Eclipse of PC1 might have all those configured properly, but PC2 just checked-out (pulled) a project from a git repo so it might not be properly equipped to run that project out of the box.

To configure project related settings , *right-click project --> properties* . You will probably need to configure the following things (My issues usually get resolved by these)

1. Build-path
2. Deployment Assembly
3. factes
4. Web Project settings

Comment: Saif thank you very much for the suggestion, at the present moment I don't have access to the "PC2" machine but tomorrow I will and I will give you feedback on that, thanks for now. Just one question: what is the directory that I should tell git to ignore, to avoid transferring the settings to other computers?

Comment: It is better if you commit those files if you and your team have no issue in using the same settings ( recommended ). But if you want to ignore some files , You can ignore files/directories like _.metadata_, _.classpath_, _.project_ and _.settings_. But keep in mind that if you ignore these settings files, you will **have** to configure the project atleast once when it is checked-out on a fresh computer. Configuration will include setting the build-path on the new Computer.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking about configuring an empty project locally and then use git to keep in sync only the source files. As soon as I get my hands on the PC I'll try it but it will be tomorrow (it's my team mate's PC).

Comment: This could be a good start http://www.bmchild.com/2012/06/git-ignore-for-java-eclipse-project.html

Comment: I think that is *exactly* what you are looking for ! Good find !

Comment: Even though I haven't had access to my mate's machine yet, I decided to mark your answer as accepted because you gave me all the elements to solve the problem effectively, thanks buddy!